# How to change mouse cursor icon?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using Url.Action() method to load view, Since heavy data is been accessed it takes time. How to change mouse cursor to wait. Please help me.

Comment: It would be nicer to put a loading gif in your view until the data is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jquery, you can try the following:

```
$('#test').on("click", function() { 
    $('body').css('cursor', 'wait'); 
});​
```

Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/krPRt/

Answer (score 9):

Using jquery u can use this

```
$('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
```

after that when loading is complete run this

```
 $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
```